# Node.js separate code parts and import into location from a separate file

Tags: node.js

I have a Node / Express server, and the main file that runs is index.js. I want to tidy the file by putting some of the code in separate files. In this case I have a long switch that I want to put in a separate file:

```
//index.js

on.ws() .... {

//code here

// SWITCH STARTS HERE
switch(something) {
  case 'one':
    // do something
    break;
  case 'hello':
    // do something else
    break;
  default:
    // default here
}
// END SWITCH

}
```

I want to put just the switch code in another external file, and then just import it in place like PHP's include. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.js:

```
var switchFile = require("./switch");
switchFile("one");
```

switchFile.js:

```
module.exports = function(something) {
  switch (something) {
    case "one":
      console.log("One");
      // do something
      break;
    case "hello":
      console.log("Hello");
      // do something else
      break;
    default:
    // default here
  }
};
```

// Output

```
One
```

Answer (score 0):

you could export from another file and include where you need [refer this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwxwv4mljv)